# Allowing non-numbers in an ExtJS date-picker input value

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, datepicker

I'm stumped on this. We have an ExtJS form where birthdate is entered. However, often the month or date of birth is not known. The user's convention is to enter xx's when not known -- xx/xx/1984.

If you need to input xx's you can type, otherwise you can use the ExtJS datepicker. Saving works properly, but if you save in the xx/xx/1984 format and then view the form again, instead of displaying the entered birthdate, the field is blank. That's because ExtJS chokes on non-numbers in the date field.

The PHP form:

```
echo "<input id=\"dobDt\" name=\"dobDt\" value=\"" . getData("dobDd","textarea") . "/" . getData("dobMm","textarea"). "/" .getData ("dobYy", "textarea") . "\" type=\"text\">
```

The ExtJs:

```
dobDtFormat = new Ext.form.DateField({
    fieldLabel: '',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    maskRe : /[\Xx{1,4}\d{1,2}\/]/,
    validationEvent: false,
    allowBlank:true
});
dobDtFormat.applyToMarkup(document.mainForm.dobDt);
```

Ext replaces the input with [its date field](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date). Any ideas on how to allow 'xx' to appear?

Also not sure how to handle 'xx' when the calendar appears and you choose a day. Ideally, we'd like the 'xx/xx/1980' to appear in the input but when you the calendar opens it interprets as '01/01/1980'.

Comment: Since ExtJS has no support for the "xx" date format out of the box, you'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ExtJS has no support for the "xx" date format out of the box, you'll have to extend the DateField object and probably override some of its functionality, such as:

```
myNamespace.MyDateField = Ext.extend(Ext.form.DateField, {
    //your configs, functions to support "xx" behavior
}
```

It also sounds like you need to really think through and more carefully define how this component should function in all of the use cases that could come up. For example, how would a user specify which fields (month, day and/or year) should have "xx" vs a number? The DateField is not designed for this so you may need to add some form fields for that purpose.

For more about creating your own customized ExtJS component, see Sencha's guide here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/components

(Look for the section entitled, "Creating Custom Components", about half way down the page.)

Hope this helps you out. Cheers!

Comment: Great response. We're working on extending the DateField object but your comment on defining the scope of use is valuable. We really need to nail down the user's workflow in this case.